# Scheme: Adding a tuple/pair to the end of a list of tuples

Tags: scheme, racket

I would like to add a pair/tuple to the end of a list of pair/tuples. I just want to give it the last number/priority.

When calling

> (addItem "Cheese" shopping-list)

I would like to get back:

> (("Milk" 1) ("Eggs" 2) ("Cheese" 3))

But I am currently getting back:

> (("Milk" 1) ("Eggs" 2) "Cheese" 3)

I am a beginner at Scheme, and I appreciate the help!

```
(define shopping-list '( ("Milk" 1) ("Eggs" 2)))

(define (addItem k lst)
  ( let ( [ queue-length (length lst)])
     (append lst (list k (+ queue-length 1)))
     )
  )

(addItem "Cheese" shopping-list)
```

Comment: I think you probably want `(append lst (list (list k (+ queue-length 1))))` (note the extra call to `list`).

Comment: If you want to change the list in place, you need to use `append!` (note the bang at the end), which will mutate the list in place as opposed to simply constructing a new. Otherwise, you need to always set the value of your variable when you call your function, like so: `(set! shopping-list (addItem "Cheese" shopping-list))`. Keep in mind that using `set!` on the variable like this will also mean that any references to the previous list won't point to the new list after the variable assignment.